# How to add target window as Pop Up for General Link Type in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, content-editor, custom-field-type

Actually i was trying to add custom target window as pop-up for general link data type of External Link's property.
[Image of External Link Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAj4S.jpg)
After this, if on the page there is any external link with target window as "Pop Up" then on the page rendering it should open pop up window.

Is it possible, if yes then please guide me?

Thanks in Advance,
Pradeep Gupta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean under popup browser window popup(leaving current window and opening link in new browser popup window) then you can use "New browser" option.

If you mean under popup something on your page. For example like it is on [popup.js](http://docs.toddish.co.uk/popup/demos/), then you should

- add(or write yourself) Javascripts that will allow to show popup.
- use javascript:popup.open("href://test.test") as link

P.S.: example was given for popup.js and code link will differ for other JS library.